# Load in MySQL data after jQuery Click Function?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a php page that loads in (the links to) images and their respective data from a MySQL table. Each image that displays on the page is the first image of an album.

**Table 1**

```
id  |  screeningId  |  mainImageUrl  |  movie  |  venue  |  location  |  date

 1          1            red.jpg       Movie1     Venue1    Location1    2015
 2          2            blue.jpg      Movie2     Venue2    Location2    2016
 3          3            orange.jpg    Movie3     Venue3    Location3    2016
 4          4            white.jpg     Movie4     Venue4    Location4    2017
```

When I click an image, I want to load in the rest of the images in a pop-up gallery - images which are stored in a *different* MySQL table.

**Table 2**

```
id | screeningId | imageUrl
 1        1        red2.jpg
 2        1        red3.jpg
 3        1        red4.jpg
 4        1        red5.jpg
 5        1        red6.jpg
 6        1        red7.jpg
 7        2        blue2.jpg
 8        2        blue3.jpg
....
....
```

For instance, if I click on `red.jpg` (from table 1), I want to load into the pop-up gallery all the images from table 2 with a `screeningId` value of `1`.

Clicking on an image from table 1 triggers a jQuery function:

`$(".img_div").click(function() {...}`

..which opens the pop-up window. I would also like to load in the images from Table 2 at this point. This is where I'm stuck.

I tried pulling the Table 2 data by nesting php tags within the click function, but this proved problematic and ridiculous.

I also considered Pulling all Table 2 data and storing it in an array when the page loads, but is that necessary?

How should I do this?

---

**Attempted Data Pull from within Script**

```
    $(".img_div").click(function() {

    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM screeningsImages WHERE screeningId = 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        ....
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you used Ajax?

Comment: Can you provide your code inside the click function?

Comment: @RafaelShkembi I don't know much about Ajax - should I go that route?

Comment: @redrif adding the attempted code for MySQL connection with `<script>` now

Comment: @coffeebot read this example. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp . Make a photo slider div and when you click the open button replace the images with the link from the ajax requests

Comment: It depends if you want to load the images without reloading the page. Ajax is an easy way to pull data from a database.

Comment: Thank you, both, I will look into solving this with Ajax

Comment: There are lots of examples using AJAX, PHP and mySQL ([web page is a little off but the content is good](https://openenergymonitor.org/forum-archive/node/107.html) and [another w3 schools tut but probably more relevant in your case](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)